# Is it possible to uninstall stock apps in Sony Xperia E3 Dual?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, uninstallation, system-apps

My device has 4GB of internal Storage, but it only shows 2GB.  Apps have taken 1.7GB of space alone. Any idea for how to uninstall the stock apps such as as Hike,Line, and others. The only option I see is to disable them but no option as uninstall.

Comment: You need to root your phone and than use titanium backup.

Answer (score 0):

## You'll need to be rooted

1. [**Gain** root access](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device).
2. Install [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) or an equivalent
3. Select **Batch Actions** (top right corner) > **Uninstall all users & system apps**
4. **Pick the system apps you want to remove**, then press the checkmark at the top right hand corner